# i want to minimize my 1st templatex

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just finished creating my first template by HTML and CSS
but I want to minimize it and make it 75% of like what it is right now.
I don't want to change all the numbers because it will take a lot of time.

**this is the 100% template:**
[image: 100% picture]

**and here is the 75% template which is better than the 1st :**
[image: 75% picture]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this css property : `transform: scale(0.75)` on your `<body>` tag, but I don't know if it would have the expected behaviour